# Installing Python Bindings for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I installed Selenium IDE 1.1.0, Selenium standalone 2.3.0 jar and Python 2.7.2.5. I also downloaded the Python bindings for Selenium. However I am unable to install the bindings.

I tried `easy_install selenium` but I get the message that no such module (selenium) exists.

Answer (score 0):

It does exist, it's in the PyPI: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are not in the right path.

a| Open cmd prompt

b| Locate the folder **C:\Python27\Scripts** and enter

```
easy_install selenium 
or
pip install selenium
```